# mysql count subtables and its subtables for its main table

Tags: mysql, join

```
Table 1 - Category

id | name

Table 2 - subcat

id | cid(category.id) | name

Table 3 - products

id | cid(category.id) | sid(subcat.id) | name

select a.* , count(b.id) as total
         from category a left join
         subcategory b on a.id=b.cid 
         group by a.id order by a.name
```

this gives the count of sub categories for each category

and I can run seperately for products so that i will get count of products for each category

what I want is the count of subcategories and the count of products for each category. How to form the query?

It should be like catename, count of (sub categories) and count of (products)

Comment: That's a bit of a nasty table design - having the main category id and subcat id in the products table could lead to inconsistencies - products in categories/subcategories that aren't related.

Comment: so what do you suggest... only subcategory id in products table would be enough isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you may have sub-categories for a given category, but no products actually listed for such sub-category, you might not get the results you expect...  This should catch both for you

```
select a.id,
       a.name, 
       BySubCat.AvailableSubCategories,
       ByProduct.ActualSubCats,
       ByProduct.ProductCount
   from
      category a

         left join
            ( select cid, count(*) as AvailableSubCategories
                 from subcat
                 group by cid ) BySubCat
            on a.id = BySubCat.cid

         left join
            ( select cid,
                     count( distinct sid ) as ActualSubCats,
                     count(*) ProductCount
                 from
                    products
                 group by
                    cid ) ByProduct
            on a.id = ByProduct.cid
  order by
     a.name
```

Comment: aaww... thanks for your response but how could i get to make up such queries... how to make up such queries... practices makes perfect isn't it... i could master any concepts but i am unable to keep track of sql... your suggestions on this

Comment: @JayapalChandran, sometimes, people try to bite off too much into a single query... that is why I try to break things down into unique elements.  In this case, two distinct types of counts going on from different sources.  The separate queries doing their own respective aggregations and joining on the common "id" makes the most sense to me.  Hopefully this query DID work for you.  Understand the smaller queries, then look at how they fit into the overall result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c.name,count(sc.id),count(sub.pcount)
from subcat sc
inner join
(
    select p.sid as subid, count(p.id) as pcount from Products p 
    inner join subcat sc on sc.id = p.sid
    group by p.sid
) sub
on sub.subid = sc.id
inner join Category c on c.id = sc.cid
group by sc.id,sub.pcount
```

Comment: aaww... thanks for your response but how could i get to make up such queries... how to make up such queries... practices makes perfect isn't it... i could master any concepts but i am unable to keep track of sql... your suggestions on this